# How to join two different criterias under Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have three tables in my database, a Student, a Classe, and an Assignement. The POJOs are as the following:

```
Student{
    Classe currentClasse;
    Set<Assignement> assignements;
}

Classe{
    Set<Assignement> assignements;
    SchoolYear schoolYear;
}

Assignement{
    Classe classe;
    Student student;
    Boolean pass;
}
```

Basically, a student has a current class, and a list of assignements (all the classes he's been assigned to).

My problem is that under hibernate, I'd like to know all the students who do not have a classe (`is null`) **OR** who are assigned to a class belonging to the schoolyear "1" but have `pass` set to `true`

I managed to make two separate criterias to get what I want:

```
session.createCriteria(Student.class)
       .add(Restrictions.isNull("classeActuelle"))
```

and

```
session.createCriteria(Student.class)
       .createAlias("assignements", "a")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("a.pass", Boolean.TRUE)
       .createAlias("a.classe","c")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("c.schoolYear", "1"))
```

but I don't know how I can "unite" those two criterias with an or...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to create an **`OR` expression** with many [`Criterion`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion.html) objects, you can use an instance of [`org.hibernate.criterion.Disjunction`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Disjunction.html). Using this object is equivalent to, but more convenient than, using several OR restrictions. To obtain a `Disjunction` object, call [`Restrictions.disjunction()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#disjunction%28%29).

If you need to create an **`AND` expression** with many `Criterion` objects, you can use an object of [`org.hibernate.criterion.Conjunction`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Conjunction.html). The [`Restrictions.conjunction()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#conjunction%28%29) method returns a `Conjunction`.

The `Disjunction` and `Conjunction` classes provide `add()` methods to apply an OR or an AND, respectively, between the criteria.

### Your case:

In your specific case, you can create an outer `Disjunction` with two `Criterion`:

- `Student`s who do not have a class;
- a `Conjunction` with two `Criterion`:

  - `Student`s assigned to a `classe` belonging to the `schoolYear` `"1"`;
  - `Student`s that have `pass` set to `true`.

### Sample code:

The following code uses both the `Disjunction` and `Conjunction` objects to construct the necessary criteria.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
             .createAlias("assignements", "a")
             .createAlias("a.classe","c");

Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
or.add(Restrictions.isNull("classeActuelle"));

Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();
and.add(Restrictions.eq("a.pass", Boolean.TRUE)
and.add(Restrictions.eq("c.schoolYear", "1"))

or.add(and);

c.add(or);
// you can use your criteria c now
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and sample code.

When I applied the above criteria, the results where the students who only have 'pass' to TRUE and 'schoolYear' to 1.
I'm guessing this is because in the criteria, we added two Aliases and the students who have 'classeActuelle' set to 'null' do not actually have an assignement at all and therefore they don't get selected when we add the join with the Assginement and Classe tables... Is there any way I can add a FULL JOIN ?

Comment: I managed to solve this issue by changing the criteria to:


    `Criteria c=session.createCriteria(Student.class).createAlias("assignements", 
        "a",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN).createAlias("a.classe", "c", 
        Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);`

Answer (score 0):

With minor changes, its has saved my time. Thanks.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
             .createAlias("assignements", "a")
             .createAlias("a.classe","c");

Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
or.add(Restrictions.isNull("classeActuelle"));

Conjunction and = Restrictions.conjunction();
and.add(Restrictions.eq("a.pass", Boolean.TRUE)
and.add(Restrictions.eq("c.schoolYear", "1"))


c.add(or);

c.add(and);
```

// you can use your criteria c now