# Hibernate criteria list must contains another list

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Given the simplified model:

```
public class Access {
  private Set<Tag> tags;
}

public class Item {
  private Set<Tag> tags;
}
```

An access grant the access on every items that fully contains his tags, no problem if the item has more tags or not.

But I have no idea how to create an hibernate criteria query for this.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to do anything other then tell Hibernate to load it always with your entity.

So option one, load always:

```
public class Access {

        @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = Tag.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(nullable = true)
        protected Set<Tag> tags;
    }
```

So the **OneToMany** annotation is telling Hibernate to look for tags in the Tag table linked to your table and to do this always: `FetchType.EAGER`.

Actually Hibernate will create two tables with a foreign key in the Tag table.

In case you wan't to lazy load this list you can set `FetchType.LAZY`, then you need to do some additional work in order to fill this list.

A simple load will fill up all values as stored:

```
session.get(Access.class, key);
```

Filtering Access list by Tags see this answer: [How to join two different criterias under Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385579/how-to-join-two-different-criterias-under-hibernate)

Comment: That's not really my need. Given an Access with (let's say) 10 tags. I want all the items for which tags containsAll the given 10 tags... In one request if possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385579/how-to-join-two-different-criterias-under-hibernate